# error importing Kibana dashboards: fail to import the dashboards in Kibana in filebeat

Tags: elastic-stack, filebeat, elk

I have installed filebeat in ubuntu. while my ELK stack running on different server. I got this error during
`service filebeat start`

```
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-07-23T20:12:15.224Z","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1274},"message":"Exiting: error importing Kibana dashboards: fail to import the dashboards in Kibana: Error importing directory /usr/share/filebeat/kibana: failed to import Kibana index pattern: 1 error: error loading index pattern: returned 408 to import file: Request Time-out: %!w(<nil>). Response: {\"statusCode\":408,\"error\":\"Request Time-out\",\"message\":\"Request Time-out\"}","service.name":"filebeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
Exiting: error importing Kibana dashboards: fail to import the dashboards in Kibana: Error importing directory /usr/share/filebeat/kibana: failed to import Kibana index pattern: 1 error: error loading index pattern: returned 408 to import file: Request Time-out: %!w(<nil>). Response: {"statusCode":408,"error":"Request Time-out","message":"Request Time-out"}
```

Anyone know how to resolve this?
Thanks

I have tried to enable apache module. when I have done setup it was throwing error

Comment: Please update the question the version of both filebeat and elasticsearch.

Comment: Most times this occurs because the connection to kibana is either misconfigured or not possible. Try verifying with for example wget/curl.